# Paginación, deshabilitar item

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de modificar el siguiente HTML desde JavaScript, lo que pretendo es que cuando en el primerhuecopagina aparezca un uno el botón anterior esté desactivado porque no hay paginas anteriores, e igual con el botón siguiente, es decir, cuando se llegue a la última página en tercerhuecopágina este esté desactivado.

```
         <div id="itemPaginacion" class="paginacion">
                <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                        <ul class="pagination">

                                <nav aria-label= "Page navigation example">
                                        <ul class="pagination">
                                                <li id="anterior" class="page-item disabled tooltip">
                                                        <a onclick = "" class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                                                <span class="tooltiptext"> Anterior</span>
                                                        </a>
                                                </li>

                                                <li id="primerhuecopagina" class="page-item navegacion tooltip">
                                                        <a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="">1</a>
                                                </li>

                                                <li id="segundohuecopagina" class="page-item tooltip">
                                                        <a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="">2</a>
                                                </li>

                                                <li id="tercerhuecopagina" class="page-item tooltip">
                                                        <a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="">3</a>
                                                </li>

                                                <li id="siguiente" class="page-item navegacion tooltip">
                                                        <a onclick = "" class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                                        <span class="tooltiptext">Siguiente</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>
                                </nav>
                        </ul>
                </nav>
        </div>
```

Este es el código para cambiar el valor de los campos al pulsar el botón siguiente:

```
        var button = document.getElementById('siguiente');
        button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var id1= 
        
       document.getElementById('primerhuecopagina').firstElementChild;
        let contenido = id1.textContent;
        const valor1 = parseInt(contenido,10) + 3;
        id1.innerHTML = valor1;
    
        var id2= 
       
      document.getElementById('segundohuecopagina').firstElementChild;
        let contenido2 = id2.textContent;
        const valor2 = parseInt (contenido2,10) + 3;
        id2.innerHTML = valor2;
    
        var id3= 
       document.getElementById('tercerhuecopagina').firstElementChild;
        let contenido3 = id3.textContent;
        const valor3 = parseInt (contenido3,10) + 3;
        id3.innerHTML =valor3;    

        if(id3.textContent = total){
            var boton = document.getElementById('anterior');
            //aquí insertar código para desactivar item siguiente
        }
    });
```